# Running Java7 in Chrome for Mac OS X (requires 64bit?)

Tags: java, macos, google-chrome, 64-bit

My home banking system requires Java for logging onto the bank - see https://www.nemid.nu/ for a description of the system (in Danish only).

This worked fine in Chrome under Mac OS X until recently when in suddenly required a new download of the Java plug-in. Unfortunately, Oracle gives me the following message:

> Chrome does not support Java 7. Java 7 runs only on 64-bit browsers and Chrome is a 32-bit browser.
>
> If you download Java 7, you will not be able to run Java content in Chrome and will need to use a 64-bit browser (such as Safari or Firefox) to run Java content within a browser. Additionally, installing Java 7 will disable the ability to use Apple Java 6 on your system.

Note that I cannot uninstall Java 7 from my Mac as this is used for my job.

What can I do now - besides using Safari for my home banking? I cannot find a 64-bit Chrome and although Chrome should [support it](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/64-bit-support), there does not seem to be [any plans for an official release](http://www.quora.com/Why-is-Chrome-for-Mac-not-64-bit-yet).

Comment: I think this question may fare better on [Superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: You pretty much know the answer here. Unless you want to help port Chrome to 64-bit Mac, port Java 7 to 32-bit Mac, or write a wrapper that lets 32-bit browsers use a 64-bit JVM, or wait for someone else to do one of the above (it may be 1 week or 5 years for a 64-bit Chrome; the others will likely never happen…), the easiest solution is to just use Safari (or Firefox or whatever) for your home banking.

Comment: Did you reopen this question on Superuser? Apparently I found a link to a fix

Comment: I did. See http://superuser.com/q/477182/87274 - which link, which fix??

Comment: Added the link at the new superuser thread: http://superuser.com/a/500172/13045

Comment: Almost 2 years later and there's still no java for chrome on mac! :-o

Comment: @Cawas As far as I understand it, the latest dev-channel Chrome exists in a 64-bit version. But... the NSAPI currently used to interface with Java will be removed soon...

Comment: @Tonny Yeah, and on top of that it's just for windows, isn't it?

Comment: @Cawas not sure, but that might well be true